# Reset a counter in recursive methods

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, static

I am trying to write a recursive method which gives me the biggest-sum-pairs of integer (neighbors) within an array. It works perfectly, but only for the first run, because i cannot reset my `static int maxSum;` "counter" which I use to check, if the current sum is bigger than the biggest sum of previous runs. maybe you can give me an hint, its the first time I work with static counters in a recursion

```java
static int maxSum = 0;
private static int getMaxPairSum(int[] workArray, int start, int end) {

   while(start < end){
       if (workArray[start] + workArray[start+1] > maxSum){
           maxSum = workArray[start] + workArray[start+1];
           return getMaxPairSum(workArray,start +1,end);
       }
       else return getMaxPairSum(workArray,start +1,end);
   }
   return maxSum;
}
```

Comment: Which is the variable you want to reset? ```maxSum``` ?

Comment: yes maxSum is the variable i want to reset after the result war returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help! I decided to write a new code, it works perfectly and is recursive :D

private static int getMaxPairSum(int[] workArray, int start, int end) {

```
    if (start==end)
        return 0;

    return Math.max((workArray[start] + workArray[start+1]), getMaxPairSum(workArray,start+1,end));
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this could be:

- Creating a temporary variable
- Assigning the value of `maxSum` to the variable
- Resetting `maxSum`
- Returning the temporary variable

Would be like this:

```java
while(start < end){
       if (workArray[start] + workArray[start+1] > maxSum){
           maxSum = workArray[start] + workArray[start+1];
           return getMaxPairSum(workArray,start +1,end);
       }
       else return getMaxPairSum(workArray,start +1,end);
   }

   int tempMaxSum = maxSum;
   maxSum = 0;
   return tempMaxSum;
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for your help :) and it worked perfectly with tempMaxSum, even though it wasn't exactly i was heading for :) have a good one

Comment: Great! Glad you found another good way! I tried making mine so that you wouldn't have to change too much code, but you definitely found a better way! Also, if you want, to make so that stackoverflow knows this  question doesn't need any more answers, you 
can set as an answer one of the 3 answers of this question, (or upvote them) !  :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you’re still thinking too much in an iterative programming mindset. In recursion, you shouldn’t really need a global variable to keep track of changes. Instead, the changes should instead propagate either up (still very iterative thinking) or down (proper recursion!) your recursion stack, with the operation (in this case a comparison) being performed at each function call in that stack.

It should be the case that transitivity of the greater than operator applies here, so the max will be the largest regardless of when in the list it happens, so it doesn’t really matter when we find it. Try to come up with some concrete examples and walk through a few iterations of your method if that seems unclear.

An example of it being passed up your recursion stack would be adding a new argument to your method, such as “maxSum” and passing that through to each call, keeping track of the max at each call. Returning from this would still feel a bit "off", though, as you'd have the value of your result once you reach the end of the list, but then would still need to return it through all the recursive calls you made to the method until it got back to the first call.

The “most recursive” approach, here, would be to let your method work with a value that hasn't been determined yet but that it knows will be determined in the future, and to do that until it reaches the end case. Once it reaches the end, it will have gotten a concrete value, which allows an undetermined value for the previous call to now be determined, which allows an undetermined value for the call before that to be determined, etc., until the first call.

Here, the comparison would be Math.max(currentSum, nextSum), where currentSum = workArray[i] + workArray[i+1] and nextSum is the value returned by the next call to getMaxPairSum, which won’t actually be determined until you get to the end of the array (your terminating case for the recursion) which will return a value to the call before it, which in returns a value to the call before it, which returns a value to the call before it, and so on until you get back to the first call and so have your final value.

For a visualization based in data structures, this means that the calculations will propagate down the recursive function call stack until the very first call, which is the bottommost item in the stack.